# How to search for a string in another array which has many strings?

Tags: c, keil

This is very simple program. But still I'm not getting the output. I want to search for the particular number in an another array. I've removed the " from MNC string to make it easy to compare with characters in other arrays.

I can able to compare `at`. But not MNC

Ex.

MNC = 53;

I want to search this `"53"` in 3 arrays.

```
    India_MNC_404[]
    India_MNC_404_1[]
    India_MNC_405[]
```

Code:

```
void APN_Select(char at[],char MNC[],char MCC[])
        {
            int i;int flag;
            char ch='"';
            char *India_MNC_404[]={"10","11","14","15","17","20","22"};
            char India_MNC_404_1[]={'1','2','3','4','5','6','7'};
            char *India_MNC_405[]={"51","52","53","54","55","56","66","67","68","70"};
                int j;
            for(i=0;MNC[i]!='\0';i++)  //To remove the " from the string.
            {
                if(MNC[i]==ch)
                {
                    for(j=i;MNC[j]!='\0';j++)
                    MNC[j]=MNC[j+1];
                    i--;
                }
            }
                printf("##############################\r\n");
                printf("%s\r\n",at);
                printf("%s\r\n",MNC);
                printf("%s\r\n",MCC);
                if (strcmp(at, "\"404\"") == 0)
            {
                printf("Network is in India\n\r");
                for(i=0;India_MNC_404[i]!='\0';i++)
                {
                    if(India_MNC_404[i]==MNC[0]) //Comparing the MNC with each element in the array
                        printf("MNC is found\r\n");

                    else
                    {
                        printf("MNC is not found- Moving to another search\n\r");
                        flag=0;
                    }
                }
                if(flag==0)
                {
                    for(i=0;India_MNC_405[i]!='\0';i++)
                {
                    if(India_MNC_405[i]==MNC[0])
                    {
                        printf("MNC is found\r\n");
                        flag=1;
                    }


                    else
                    {
                        printf("MNC is not found\n\r");
                    }
                }
            }

            }
}
```

Comment: `MNC[i]!='\0'`? Pointer char equality check? And this is not [mcve]

Comment: Are warnings enabled when you compile?